# json return empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery

when my page loads, I'm using .ajax to calls server side code and return json. The issue I'm having is I get an empty array. So inside my "success: function(data)", it's saying data[0].id is undefined. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/length) before accessing it, return or do something else if it's `0`, like this:

```
if(data.length === 0) {
  alert("empty!");
  return;
}
//it has entries, carry on...
var id = data[0].id;
```

Comment: @ Nick Craver -- Ah ha! Yes, that did the trick Nick. Thank you so much.